# Как разработать мобильную игру/приложение на С++

Tags: visual-c++, разработка-игр, библиотеки, мобильные-приложения

Хоть я и недостаточно знаю С++ для разработки подобных приложений, мне бы просто хотелось узнать существуют ли какие либо относительно хорошие библиотеки/фреймворки для разработки игр/мобильных приложений на С++, я понимаю что есть более удачные решения по разработке (например react native для мобильных приложений, а для игр говорят удобно C#) но мне почему то очень нравится С++ как язык и ещё его синтаксис, мне достаточно просто знать какие есть на данный момент хорошие и перспективные штуки для разработке в этой сфере, ведь согласитесь не очень приятно что то изучать когда не знаешь к чему придёшь.

Comment: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x

Answer (score 0):

Для игр можно использовать [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/) или [cocos2d-x](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x), а для мобильных приложений можно использовать [Qt](https://www.qt.io/).

Answer (score -2):

Для разработки игр на C++ есть очень популярный движок [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/). У него хорошая графика из коробки, визуальный редактор и множество фич. Сам движок от Epic Games.

Если вы не гонитесь за графикой и вам нужно создавать 2D игры, то можете посмотреть в сторону [Godot](https://godotengine.org/). Движок поддерживает несколько языков: C++, C# и GDScript

На счёт приложений, то тут однозначно - [WinForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/overview/?view=netdesktop-5.0) и [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin), в другие стороны даже не смотрите